Highlighting cell if data doesn't match column on different tab
I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs. Basically, I would like for Column B on tab 2 to highlight any cell that doesn't match any of the cells on Column A on tab 1.
The formula I'm using doesn't seem to work because it is matching exact cells. I would like it to behave more like this:


Thank you!
I tried =ISERROR(MATCH(B23, Sheet1!$A2:$A999, 0)) and I was expecting it to look at the entire column on Sheet 1, not to match exactly cell to cell.

Your formula seems to works for me. Have you check for extra spaces at the end of the strings?

B23 should likely be B2 or at least the row number equal to the start of the conditional formatting range.

Here's one way:

Select the range for conditional formatting in in Tab 2 by selecting the top most cell and dragging the selection to the end

in example I selected a1:a32


Add new rule Classic > Format only cells that contain > Blanks
Select Custom Format… and press OK without selecting anything



Add a new rule with formula
Enter your rule as before =ISERROR(MATCH($A1, Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000,0))
Make sure to specify relative reference for row as in $A1
Move the rule for blanks to the top and select "Stop if true"


